# ASP.NET WebAPI Routing Issue

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Say I have the following actions;

```
// api/products
public IEnumerable<ProductDto> GetProducts()
public ProductDto GetProduct(int id)

// api/products/{productId}/covers
public IEnumerable<CoverDto> GetCovers(int productId)
```

**What would be the best way to create a route to use as a shortcut to a "master" product?** i.e. `api/products/master`

I've tried adding a master controller, and routing the above to it, but I get the following error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' 
of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'ProductDto GetProduct(Int32)' 
in 'ProductsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, 
a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
```

To fix this, I've tried updating the normal product route to `api/products/{id:int}`, but to no avail.

I would like to end up with the following; where the only difference is that the "master" product would be obtained by a *code*, not an id

```
api/products
api/products/1
api/products/1/covers
api/products/master
api/products/master/covers
```

Answer (score 0):

These routes should do the trick:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "MasterAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/master/{action}",
    defaults: new { action = "GetProduct", id = 999 } // or whatever your master id is
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Action",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { action = "GetProduct" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

You will need to change the parameter name of the `GetCovers` method from `productId` to `id`, or you will need to add some more routes that define `{productId}`.

With the "covers" routes, you will either need to change the URIs to be:

```
api/products/1/getcovers
api/products/master/getcovers
```

Or, if you want to keep the URIs intact, you would need to change your action method to look like this

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<CoverDto> Covers(int id)
```

Comment: Thanks, but like I said, the "master" product needs to be obtained by a **product code**, not a 999 id like you have. This would mean another controller action, but I don't know how to do the routes then.

Comment: I guess I don't know what you mean by product code. What is an example of a product code?